# Tabulator: How to get the set of column (fields) that are currently grouped?

Tags: tabulator

In tabulator we have:

`table.setGroupBy("gender");  or table.setGroupBy(["gender","age"]);`

I'm looking for a way to query the table and find out what that current list of groupBy is.  I can't find any prototype function that seems to do this. Something like `table.getGroupBy()` ?

I did try iterating over columns, but can't find a function or property that will tell me this.  Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `getGroups` function:

```js
var groups = table.getGroups();
```

This will return an array of [Group Components](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/components#component-group), each one representing one of the top level groups of the table.

You can then iterate over these and get the fields and keys for each group using the `getField` and `getKey` functions on the component:

```js
var groups = table.getGroups();

groups.forEach((group) => {
    var key = group.getKey();
    var field = group.getField();
});
```

If you are working in a table with nested groups then you can call the `getSubGroups` function on each component to get an array of the child group components for that group:

```js
var groups = table.getGroups();

groups.forEach((group) => {
    var key = group.getKey();
    var field = group.getField();

    var children = group.getSubGroups();
});
```

You could then recurse through these until you have all of the data you need.

Comment: Thanks; my code has been in a production environment now for months so I will have to try your approach locally to see if I can get it to work.  It seems to be a little complex though - I was hoping for a very simple getGroupBy() that would provide a getter for the original setter of setGroupBy().  Which the object I mentioned in my self-answer does seem to give me...maybe I'm missing something where that is not a good enough idea (?)

Comment: To be fair, if you arn't using any complex grouping scenarios then your simple approach will work, the only place it will faulter is if you are using things like complex grouping functions, if you arent then you can just ignore me

Comment: Well I appreciate your insight and taking the time to address my question.  The Tabulator utility is a gem, which I also appreciate - so no, will not ignore you.  I do only use simple groupings, and I understand the point about more complex.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it, not documented but hopefully it can be trusted:

`table.options.groupBy`

Comment: setGroupBy() / getGroups() ? http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/group#manage

Comment: Thanks but getGroups() only returns the first level grouping .  I am looking for the exact inverse of setGroupBy()  - which table.options.groupBy is.   setGroupBy(['a','b','c']) then table.options.groupby == ['a','b','c'].  getGroups() is a single element array containing one object, the column definition for 'a'.

Comment: CC that is not the case, i will provide a more detailed answer that will explain how this works correctly